# How do I calculate the position of the Earth in a 3d engine?

Tags: vectors

If I place the Sun at the center of a 3d engine (0,0,0), how do I calculate the position of the Earth ?

What about calculating how complete the Earths' rotational period is at any given time? (Ex: at this instant is the Earth half-way through its rotation period? a quarter? three-quarters? etc.)

I don't need the distance to be to scale.

Thanks

Comment: 1) you give the earth an initial condition an model the force of gravity on it

Comment: I'd echo what JMLCarter said, and have done lots of such modelling in C. But what, exactly, are you trying to do? That kind of modelling may or may not be appropriate for your purposes. Say what you want to do, what programming tools you're using, what math background you have, etc, etc. Your question's completely inadequate as written.